# do you need to instal odbc driver on a mac to query a postgresql (pgadmin 4) database?

Tags: excel, odbc, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

Yesterday I sat the whole day installing odbc drivers on my work computer.
Why? so that I could query our pgadmin 4 database using postgresql 9.6, and populate my excel workbook with info.

Now, my colleagues need to use my excel workbook, so that they also can see the data on our company secrets. But not all of them uses PC. One has Macbook.
Hence the question.
Do I need to go through the same process on her mac, or how do I do it?

And this question is also important: in order to use excel and query a postgresql database on a mac what do I need?

Comment: Yes, in order to access an ODBC data source from a given machine you need to have an ODBC driver installed on that machine.. So, unless your colleague's Mac already has a PostgreSQL ODBC driver installed, somebody will have to install one. For the official PostgreSQL ODBC driver, that would involve something [like this](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/unix-compilation.html).

Comment: Alright Gordd Thompson, I see what you're saying. 
Now I also thought I had found on their webpage  odbc drivers for mac, but then it looks like they don't.....
Now all I gotta do is to find the drivers and to add it into the system files etc etc. Hopefully the page you sent me will be of some aid.
Cheers m8!

Comment: The page you sent is probably really good for someone who knows their way around these sort of things already. As for me, I am a novice when it comes to installing through what appears to be cmd commands, and using postgresql and odbc drivers. I was looking for something more novice friendly. If you see what I'm saying :D...... I really chose the perfect nickname "Karl PRO" ......irony